# How do I point to a particular installation of simplesamlphp with the simplesamlphp_auth module?

Tags: 8, composer

I am trying to integrate our company's SSO into our Drupal installation. As a POC to see if it even works, I have a copy of the SimpleSAMLPhp Library located at `/foo/bar/simplesamlphp`. I configured my apache vhost and the SAML configs and that's all fine for now.

Per the instructions from Acquia on [this page](https://docs.acquia.com/resource/using-simplesamlphp-acquia-cloud-site/#install-the-simplesamlphp-auth-drupal-module), I tried installing the `drupal/simplesamlphp_auth` module.

```
composer require drupal/simplesamlphp_auth
```

This installed the module and as a dependency, installed *a second copy* of the `simplesamlphp` library in `vendor/simplesamlphp`. Now it looks like the module `simplesamlphp_auth` is using the installation in `vendor`.

**How do I configure this module to use the one I already placed** in `/foo/bar/simplesamlphp`? There doesn't seem to be any options on the page `/admin/config/people/simplesamlphp_auth`.

I have configuration files that I would like to avoid copying over to the `vendor` directory after each deployment if possible, since that's not as secure as keeping the configs outside of the project altogether.

**EDIT 1**

Clarification on the configuration files: I need to define configuration files in `/foo/bar/simplesamlphp/config` in order for it to work. These configuration files are missing from `vendor/simplesamlphp/config` and without them the application encounters a fatal error. As stated in the Acquia document above, the library lives outside of `vendor/` or `docroot/` in their setup.

Comment: Whats in the vendor directory is the literal library, not the module. The module is an implementation that leverages the library classes located in `vendor/`. If you are using composer to get the module, you might as well be using it to manage dependencies as well. The modules composer.json file likely lists it as a dependency, so it gets fetched. "I have configuration files that I would like to avoid copying over to the vendor directory" - what does this mean?

Comment: @Kevin The copy of the library in the `vendor/` directory is missing configuration files, without them the site gives a WSOD. On deployment, I would have to take an additional step of copying the configurations I have `/foo/bar/simplesamlphp/config` to the one in `vendor/simplesamlphp/config`. It seems a little weird to modify the vendor directory outside of a `composer` command.

Comment: Not exactly, this is something I am doing in my deployment script:

  `- rm -rf $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/config` and 
  `- ln -s $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/simplesamlphp/config $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/config`  .... this points the config folder to a location in your project outside of vendor. The library won't know the difference.

Comment: I'm also doing something very similar to what Kevin's doing. Haven't found a better way to approach it yet

Comment: Yeah, I guess that'll have to do. It seems simple enough to script from a build tool like Jenkins. I just wish the instructions from Acquia were a little clearer on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a symlink to your temporary SAML folder

```
ln -s /foo/bar/simplesamlphp ./simplesaml
```

In settings.php add next line:

```
$settings['simplesamlphp_dir'] = '/foo/bar/simplesamlphp';
```

In config.php file in your /simplesamlphp/config library add following settings:

```
// Load necessary environmental data
$ps = json_decode($_SERVER['PRESSFLOW_SETTINGS'], TRUE);
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$db = $ps['databases']['default']['default'];

// Define basic variables
$config = array (
   'baseurlpath' => 'https://'. $host .':443/simplesaml/', // SAML should always connect via 443
   'certdir' => 'cert/',
   'loggingdir' => '/files/private/log/',
   'datadir' => 'data/',
   'tempdir' => '/tmp/simplesaml',
   'store.type' => 'sql',
   'store.sql.dsn' => 'mysql:host='. $db['host'] .';port='. $db['port'] .';dbname='. $db['database'],
   'store.sql.username' => $db['username'],
   'store.sql.password' => $db['password'],
);
```

Now if you open your-site.com/simplesaml url in the browser, /foo/bar/simplesamlphp library will be used instead of vendor folder.